# Dynamic forms rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I'm stuck on something I didn't think would be so difficult.  I'm making a fantasy football website for a client.  I have a separate table for players and roster.  Players being the global pool of available players to choose and the roster being the user's roster where they add available players to their team.  For the new roster form, where a player is added to the user's roster, the form expects values such as (in order) position, player_id, name, teamname (user's teamname), user's team_id, user_id.  I want a dynamic form where position is selected via a dropdown select_tag or form.select, that selection then populates the player selection drop down to show only players of that position.  I cannot seem to get this function to work.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Update:  I finally solved the issue using a separate local form in the new player page and sending the `select_tag` value to the controller where it became the string for showing only the players at that position.  By doing it before the form was rendered the `onchange` method didn't try to submit the form and everything populated as expected.

If anyone has a similar issue I'd be happy to advise you on it, the specific answer will be depending on your specific set up and requirements.